# center checkbox in the first column of bootstrap table

Tags: css, bootstrap-table

I have a bootstrap table.
In the first column, there's the checkbox column.
However, when I narrow the width of the first column, the checkbox remains at the same absolute position without move into the center of the column:

[image]

How could I make the checkbox move left to make it in the center of the column when narrow the width of the first column?

As I use bootstrap table and restAPI, there's only table header with out table body.

```html
<style>
   .data-checkbox{
   max-width: 70px;
   }
</style>
<table  contenteditable='true' class="table table-bordered table-xl" width="100%"  cellspacing="0" style="font-size: 1.0rem;"
   id="bk-table"
   data-toggle="table"
   data-toolbar="#toolbar"
   data-cookie="true"
   data-cookie-id-table="materialId"
   data-show-columns="true"
   data-show-export="true"
   data-export-types="['excel','pdf']"
   data-height="1650"
   data-click-to-select="true"
   data-id-field="id"
   data-show-footer="true"
   data-url="/api/materials/"
   data-query-params="queryParams"
   data-remember-order="true"
   data-pagination="true"
   data-side-pagination="client"
   data-total-field="count"
   data-data-field="results">
   <thead class="thead-dark" >
      <tr contenteditable='true'>
         <th data-field="state" class="data-checkbox"  data-checkbox="true"></th>
         <th class ='courseCode' data-field="courseCode"  data-formatter="renderCourse">Course Code</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: In your code not visible a checkbox input field, however, if your code is placed separately it works fine, please check the example - https://codepen.io/alekskorovin/pen/mdBJQPO the only Bootstrap class 'text-center' was added. It could be the case that other CSS interfere your table CSS classes

Comment: <th data-field="state" class="data-checkbox"  data-checkbox="true"></th>   is a checkbox input in bootstrap table

Comment: Could you please then add some information on which CSS and JS should be included?

Comment: The css is on top of the table. No javascript used, just a bootstrap table.

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue using that starter template - https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/getting-started/introduction/ this checkbox looks fine